# How to read javascript variable from BrowserField

Tags: javascript, blackberry, browserfield

I'm using 5.0 field2.BrowserField and executeScript method for invoking javascript. I try to read
 single javascript value, but I'm getting  ThrownValueWrapper  error

```
Object obj = browser.executeScript("javascript:varName;");
```

how to read javascript variable value?

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj = browser.executeScript("varName");
```